# Set a minimum threshold value for a function

Tags: function-construction

I have defined the following function in Mathematica

```
al[z_] := (a/((1 + a*(b/(2 Pi))*Log[z/Mz])))
```

(`a` and `b` are defined constants) Now I want to put in a variable `x` that I will integrate over from 0 to 100, but for low values of `x` (up to 3) I want the function `al` to be fixed, i.e., `z` should be 3 for `x < 3` and `x` for `x > 3`.

However, I only want this constraint on `al` when I fill in `x`. Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: Why not use `Piecewise[]`, then?

Comment: Well, I use the function multiple times and if I wanted to fill in a value, say $y$, I did not want that constraint, and trying to be as compact as possible I was wondering whether there was another option. Anyway, thanks. In the end for my specific case the option     Min[al[x],al[3]] worked fine as well.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`Clip`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Clip.html):

```
al[ Clip[x, {3, Infinity}] ]
```

Comment: Note that this is equivalent to suggestion by @J.M. to use `Piecewise`. Evaluate `Clip[x, {xmin, xmax}] // PiecewiseExpand` and `Clip[x, {3, Infinity}] // PiecewiseExpand`

Comment: Cheers, turns out Min[al[x],al[3]] works as well in my particular case